# Upload files to s3 via curl gives 400 error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

**EDIT**

I had a hard time debugging with PHP and even Golang. But it turns out, directly sending a Curl Request solved my problem

```
curl -v -F $Signature -F $Date -F $Credential -F $Key -F $Algo -F $Policy -F $File $Url
```

I did try to convert the request to PHP, but I still could not get it to work. So, I am sending this request via `shell_exec()`

**EDIT ENDS**

My service provider doesn't provide the AWS S3 access key and secret, but only allows me to upload files via a form prescribed by AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html). Hence, I am exploring options to upload files to their server using a program to automate my stuff.

The form works like a charm. But when I emulate the same request via PHP CURL, it constantly gives me **400 errors**. I have removed the unwanted form parts from the example in AWS and tried to keep the request in CURL as close as possible.

Can someone point me to what is wrong with my Curl request?

**Working HTML Form**

```bash
<form action="https://<CLIENT NAME>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="something.pdf" /><br />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<SOME key>/20221017/REGION/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20221017T162325Z" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value='<SIGNATURE>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<POLICY>" />
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
```

**Sample PHP-Curl Code I am trying**

```bash
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnUpload'])) {
    $url = "https://<SERVICE PROVIDER>.s3.amazonaws.com/";
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    if ($filedata != '') {
        $headers = array(
            "enctype: multipart/form-data", 
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
            "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
            "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
            "Keep-Alive: 300",
            "Connection: keep-alive"
        ); 

        
        $postfields = array(
            "file" => "", 
            "x-amz-signature" => "<SIGNATURE>", 
            "x-amz-date" => "20221017T173731Z", 
            "x-amz-credential" => "<EY>/20221017/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request",
            "key" => "<SAMPLE.FILE>", 
            "policy" => "<POLICY>",
            "x-amz-algorithm" => "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.42',
            CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'gzip, deflate, br'
        ); // cURL options

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_exec($ch);

        if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
           
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
                $errmsg = "File uploaded successfully";
        } else {
           
            $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        print_r($info);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}


?>
<form action="" method="post" name="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
  <td>Upload</td>
  <td align="center">:</td>
  <td><input name="file" type="file" id="file"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="btnUpload" type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I highly doubt AWS would accept an insecure transfer. ` CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,`

Comment: @Misunderstood, I have disabled that as I was using localhost and it was triggering an error. But, can that resolve my case?

Comment: @Misunderstood That option is for whether the *PHP script* verifies the certificate it *receives from* AWS; AWS won't know that it's being used.

Comment: A 400 error usually comes with a detailed error message in the response. Did it in this case? If so, please [edit] that detail into the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just the way you've stripped out private information, but I can't see where you're actually including the file contents in your request. You have a variable called `$filedata`, but you set it to a file _name_ with `$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` and then never use it again; then in the `$postfields` array, you just have `"file" => "",`

Comment: @IMSoP Good point.  Did not think that one through.  I related it to the curl --insecure option.

Comment: @IMSoP, I even tried it with Golang. But the result is the same. There is no detailed error message from AWS. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Chilarai We can only help with code you show. The code you've shown here does not attempt to send any data.

Comment: @IMSoP, the working html uses `<form action=""` to achieve the functionality. It doesn't have any other code. HEre is the link for reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

For the PHP-Curl, I have already posted the code

Comment: Have a look at my comment from 2 days ago. Your "filedata" variable, which contains a filename, is never used; and your "file" key in the post data is set to an empty string. Nowhere is the actual file content retrieved or passed up AWS.

Comment: @IMSoP, I did put the file name in the post, but it didn't help. Hence, I send a curl request directly via `shell_exec` which worked.

Comment: @Chilarai It's not the file **name** that you wanted to send to AWS, it's the file **content**.

Comment: @IMSoP, it doesn't matter. I tried without any filename or file data on the postman. It worked. There must be some issue that I could not figure out using PHP which worked with normal cURL

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

> Hmm. I can't seem to get it work even with curl on localhost. Do you
> have any idea? I can't possibly think of any reason how AWS would
> detect my request –Chilarai

The way I did this was to make an HTML page with the form from AWS.  I submitted the form in Firefox.  I then went to the Network tab in Firefox's Developer Tools, Network tab, right clicked the request and copied the request ass curl. 
I then went to https://curlconverter.com/php/ and converted the Firefox curl and converted it to PHP curl code.

[image: Firefox Developer Tools Inspector]

**END OF UPDATE**

I do not think the problem is your code.  The problem is more likely Cloudflare or something similar . They have made themselves Internet traffic cops.  I would guess it may be a security certificate issue.  AWS may not want you and your curl to access their site.

It has been reported that Cloudflare has profiling and fingerprinting the TLS/SSL handshaking for Browsers and they compare the handshaking fingerprint with the User Agent and if it does not match you get the "Cloudflare 403 Forbidden"

If you Google "Cloudflare 403 Forbidden" there a no shortage of articles on the subject. 
  These guys have fix a few causes of the 403.
[PHP cURL 403 forbidden – How to solve it](https://%20https://bobcares.com/blog/php-curl-403-forbidden/)

---

▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄

---

I see you are using the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,`.  It would be nice to see what the request header looks like.

Your "Working HTML Form" did not have a URL that I could test so I used the "example.html" form in the link you provided.
I made no changes to the HTML.
Not even these two lines of HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>" />
```

This is the request that Firefox made converted to PHP curl.
I got no response, the connection was reset before the request was completed.
I have no way to test this code without an AWS account.
It may be useful to compare your curl request header.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------127362855031316784522161324660',
    'Origin' => '<http://my test site>.com',
    'DNT' => '1',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'Referer' => <http://my test site>.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="key"\r\n\r\nuser/user1/\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"\r\n\r\npublic-read\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_redirect"\r\n\r\nhttp://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"\r\n\r\nimage/jpeg\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-uuid"\r\n\r\n14365123651274\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-server-side-encryption"\r\n\r\nAES256\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="X-Amz-Credential"\r\n\r\nAKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="X-Amz-Algorithm"\r\n\r\nAWS4-HMAC-SHA256\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="X-Amz-Date"\r\n\r\n20151229T000000Z\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-tag"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Policy"\r\n\r\n<Base64-encoded policy string>\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="X-Amz-Signature"\r\n\r\n<signature-value>\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1-1.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"\r\n\r\nUpload to Amazon S3\r\n-----------------------------127362855031316784522161324660--\r\n');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

And the actual request header

```
POST / undefined
Host: sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------134195551233585171272903941613
Content-Length: 26595
Origin: http://<my test site>.com
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://<my test site>.com/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Comment: Thanks. The working form is based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html.

If you look at the HTML, there is no CURL, but everything is handled using `<form action="AWS_LINK" />`

That is what I am trying to replicate on CURL and it is not working

Comment: Hmm.  I can't seem to get it work even with curl on localhost. Do you have any idea? I can't possibly think of any reason how AWS would detect my request

Comment: @Chilarai I added an update.   Can you not show me your request header looks like from `curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)`, that was the first thing I asked for.  I cannot help you without more info.  Keep in mind that if it Cloudflare keeping you out because they think you are a security threat because you are using curl,  it will not be easy to get around them.

Comment: I have sent a curl request directly and it worked. I have edited my question with the working curl request. If you can covert that to PHP, that will be helpful to others maybe

Comment: @Chilarai I understand.  This stuff is not simple.  Helping others is the right thing to do.  And the Amazon AWS documentation is typically horrific.  I am very impressed you got it to work.  I was not very optimistic.  Cloudflare is a major obstacle.  I have no doubt your question solution will help others.  I am humbled to be of help.